# Folders on another partition from Windows are read-only and can't run .exe files (dualboot with Ubuntu)

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, dualboot

I have a SSD on which I installed Windows 10, then Ubuntu 20.04 (Linux Lite).

On Windows I have 2 partitions:
`C:` - where Windows is installed
`E:` - I use it to have access to my files from both operating systems.

#### I have the following problems:

1. all folders on **E:** are read-only
2. when I try to run an .exe file stored on **E:** I get the following message (same thing happens when I Right-Click -> Run as administrator):
   `Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to acccess the item.`

#### What I've tried:

1. If I uncheck the *read-only* property in a folder's properties, after opening the properties again, it shows me that they are still read only. I guess it has to to with inheritance.
2. If I enable all permissions for Everyone for an .exe file, then I can run it. But, for Local Disk E: I have all permissions, excepting special ones, enabled (for Everyone, Authenticated Users, SYSTEM, some random name that starts with *S-1* and then it's just numbers and dashes, Administators, Users). I tried to add my username, but nothing happens.
3. Playing with the owner of directories, but I get some errors. Also, I tried setting full permissions for every entry in the Security Tab for a cetain folder And I got

> Error Applying Security
>
> > An error occurred while applying security information to:
> > E:\...\...\...\.git
> > Failed to enumerate objects in the container. Access is denied.
> > 4. I don't remember what I did, but I also tried some command to modify the permissions in the cmd.
> > 5. I also saw that certain folders have a **Deny | Everyone | Traverse folder / execute file** rule in the Advanced Security Tab. I don't know if it's related, but a particular folder that had such a Deny rule was created on Linux. My entry for **E:** in */etc/fstab*: `UUID=F85E525C5E52142A /mnt/e ntfs permissions 0 0`

Also, I have **Controlled Folder Access** turned off.

How can I fix this? And, by fix, I mean: being able run to .exe files, not having the directories read-only and having all the permissions to default.

Also, it might a question for a different post or it might prove helpful, but are [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61i9f.png) the right and or default permissions for the files/folders inside the mounted partition from Windows. Right in the sense of being able to run executables.

#### EDIT: Answer to @Tom Yan

I tried various options for the mount the parititions, but none of them matched what I wanted - to be able to run programs on that partition and default/normal permissions for every single file and folder. In the end, I stuck with that one. But they are all a mess, on both systems.

Regarding what I read in  the User Mapping section of the man page for ntfs-3g, if I put in /etc/fstab  the entry `UUID=F85E525C5E52142A /mnt/e ntfs-3g defaults 0 0` and create E:\.NTFS-3G\UserMapping with the contents:

```
<my username on Linux>::<the SID of my account on Windows>
root::<the SID of C:\Users\Administrator>
```

then it should fix the problem regarding running programs on partition E: ?
But, then, how can I fix all the permissions that I've messed up with?

Comment: "some random name that starts with S-1" - This means you have files that have permissions for users unknown to the Windows installation.  The numbers are UIDs.

Comment: See the `User Mapping` section of the man page of ntfs-3g. Why do you even use the `permissions` mount option anyway?

Comment: @TomYan, I've answered you in the post, because of the characters limit for comments.

Comment: FYI don't bother with that "Read only" checkbox on the folder. It doesn't mean what you think it means. Read the note in parenthesis.